# ASP.NET Core app deploy to AWS Beanstalk using GitHub Actions

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, github, yaml, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to build a CD pipeline using the GitHub Actions and AWS Beanstalk (Linux) for my ASP.NET Core 3.1 app.
I have configured the YML file as follows:

```
- name: dotnet Build
  run: dotnet build src/SLNNAME.sln -c Release --no-restore

- name: dotnet Publish
  run: |
    dotnet publish src/SLNNAME.Server/SLNAME.Server.Web/SLNNAME.Server.Web.csproj -c Release -o staging_SLNNAME_server -r linux-x64

- name: Build deployment package
  run: zip -r staging-server-deploy.zip staging_SLNNAME_server
```

..

```
- name: Deploy to AWS Beanstalk
  uses: einaregilsson/beanstalk-deploy@v10
  with:
    aws_access_key: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
    aws_secret_key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
    region: ${{ secrets.AWS_REGION }}
    application_name: SLNNAME-staging-app-web
    environment_name: SLNNAME-staging-server
    version_label: "staging-app-web-${{ steps.format-time.outputs.replaced }}"
    deployment_package: staging-server-deploy.zip
```

But an error occurs during the deployment to AWS. In particular, looking at the Beanstalk logs I can read the following error:

```
[ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [CheckProcfileForDotNetCoreApplication]. Stop running the command. Error: error stat /var/app/staging/staging_SLNNAME_server/SLNNAME.dll: no such file or directory with file /var/app/staging/staging_SLNNAME_server/SLNNAME.dll
```

Basically, I think it is looking for a DLL with the solution name instead of the project name - SLNName.Server.Web. I wonder yet where it is picking up the solution name, since it is not part of the zip file.
I gave a try with the `--self-contained` flag as well, but the error is exactly the same.

I have this error even if I try to publish the solution using the AWS toolking Visual Studio extension.

The only way I have found to fix this is to change the project output DLL name to match the solution one, but it doesn't make any sense to me - I might have more problems in future.

Thanks

Comment: I realized that a Procfile could fix the issue according to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/dotnet-linux-platform-bundle-app.html). So I created one placed in the solution root but referenced to the project to deploy. Here's the file content: `web: dotnet staging_<placeholder>_server/SLNNAME.Server.Web.dll `, but AWS doesn't read it for some reason

Comment: I'm hitting this error now - any luck, @Krusty?

Comment: @Stachu Not yet. I have posted on [AWS forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=324610&tstart=0) but I didn't receive any answer from moderators

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today I received an email from AWS support saying the issue has been fixed.
I have tried it and actually it works!

Please be sure to use Linux 2/2.0.1 as platform

Answer (score 1):

**Warning: This is a workaround, not a solution!**

On the project that's failing to deploy, change the "Assembly name" in Project Properties / Application tab, to the name of the DLL it's missing (typically the solution name or the first period-separated part of the namespace).

i.e. "SLNNAME"

Then, redeploy your beanstalk app and it should work.

Comment: Yes I confirm that. That's the workaround I have been using

Answer (score 0):

I have opened a ticket on AWS platform and this issue has been stated as a bug by the support team.

They replied to me with:

> I reached out to internal team and informed the team regarding the bug. [...] I have added your voice for this request I raised with internal team to add more weightage on the issue. Currently, I am unable to provide you with ETA [...] you can certainly be assured that the internal team is looking into this issue and fix it as quickly as possible

Hoping they will fix this soon as possible